# Angular: how to apply parent properties to children?

Tags: angular, typescript, data-structures

I have a list of objects like this :

```
const items: Item[]
```

and `Item` is like this:

```
export interface Item{
   parent?: string,
   label?: string,
   color?: string,
   isParent?: string
}
```

in `items` there are child items and parent items, e.g. child item :

```
{parent: labelA, label: labelB, color: red, isParent: false}
```

and e.g. parent item :

```
{parent: labelA, label: labelA, color: blue, isParent: true}
```

Now I want to find all children items, then update their `color` to their parent's `color`, how can I do this efficiently ?

e.g. for child item above, as its parent is labelA and the color is blue, I need to update the child color from red to blue.

Comment: Not sure if most efficient way of doing it. I would create a recordset with key as parentId, value the object. Then iterate over the array of items and access directly that record set by id to get the colors. Accessing like that is a direct access without iteration.However to create that object we need to iterate 1 time, and to change the colors another time. Is not bad if you have a small set. Also consider to have that object of colors created manually https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-954ebc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Comment: Please check the example link I created https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-954ebc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Answer (score 0):

This example demonstrates a solution using Map to store parent colors:

```
interface Item {
    parent?: string;
    label?: string;
    color?: string;
    isParent?: boolean;
}

const items = [
    {
        parent: 'blue',
        label: 'red',
        color: 'red',
        isParent: false
    },
    {
        parent: 'blue',
        label: 'yellow',
        color: 'yellow',
        isParent: false
    },
    {
        label: 'blue',
        color: 'blue',
        isParent: true
    },
    {
        parent: 'red',
        label: 'green',
        color: 'green',
        isParent: false
    },
    {
        label: 'red',
        color: 'red',
        isParent: true
    }
] as Item[];
const parentColors = new Map<string | undefined, string | undefined>();

console.log(items); // before processing

// populate parent colors for future reference
items.forEach(item => {
    if (item.isParent) {
        parentColors.set(item.label, item.color);
    }
});
// iterate children and replace their colors with their parents colors
items.forEach(item => {
    if (!item.isParent) {
        item.color = parentColors.get(item.parent);
    }
});

console.log(items); // after processing
```